# Ошибка Error:(24, 45) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to SyndEntry

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package giftapp.rsstest;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

public class FeedWriter {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/manishchhabra27");
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    // Reading the feed
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(httpcon));
    List entries = feed.getEntries();
    Iterator itEntries = entries.iterator();

    while (itEntries.hasNext()) {
        SyndEntry entry = itEntries.next();
        System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Link: " + entry.getLink());
        System.out.println("Author: " + entry.getAuthor());
        System.out.println("Publish Date: " + entry.getPublishedDate());
        System.out.println("Description: " + entry.getDescription().getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, укажите строку, на которой эта ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо явное приведение типов.

```
SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) itEntries.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема в неправильной работе с `HttpURLConnection`.
Попробуйте так:

```
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpcon.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Если нужен GET запрос
httpcon.connect();
```